# JasperReports: Unmerge columns in new excel sheet

Tags: excel, jasper-reports

I'm having problems with excel exports in Jasper Reports. The output excel files of my reports have unwanted merged cells, depending on the report template I use for each report. 
I'm displaying report template in first excel sheet, and "Column Header" and "Data" in the second excel sheet. 
what I'm trying to do is to ignore merged cells in second sheet. 
I use

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.before.row" value="true"/>
```

property to create second sheet.

I'm not allowed to change the template, so I shoud find a way to ignore merged cells in the second sheet, here is a screenshot of my excel file

[image]

as you can see, in the second column there are four merged cells. Any ideas to ignore those unwanted merged cells?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I couldn't find a way to solve the problem**

I've persuaded our customer, not to use, or to modify the template in the first excel worksheet. After modifying the template now everything looks fine:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found that expanding the width of the entire report and shifting cells to the right of the area where the merge happens cleaned it up for me. The columns where the merge happened was reduced to 0 in width and empty when I ran the report again. If you don't mind the extra columns being there as they are all but invisible then this solution is confirmed to work.

Answer (score -1):

For that problem I have exact answer that is remove boarders of the page..then you will get sucess